Unable to find audio files in Next.js
I am currently having issues importing my audio files into a redux slice.
Currently I am trying to get my audio files from the
app > public > audio directory.
I have tried to get my audio files via 2 different directories. But this still did not work..

const pomodoroErrorAlert = "/audio/pomodoroSuccessAlert.wav";
const pomodoroSuccessAlert = "../../public/audio/pomodoroErrorAlert.wav";

This is the error I got in return..
:3001/public/audio/pomodoroErrorAlert.wav:1
GET http://localhost:3001/public/audio/pomodoroErrorAlert.wav net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Next.js serves static files from 'public' directory at the root of the project. In your question you said you tried both import paths but the error you are receiving is suggesting that the second audio file is not being imported correctly.
If so try changing the second import without the 'public' directory in the import path like so:
const pomodoroSuccessAlert = "/audio/pomodoroErrorAlert.wav";
